# Mix arbitrary number of audio files into single stereo audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm currently working on a karaoke application and need to merge arbitrary number (from 1 up to 12) input tracks together with a song track into single output audio file that should be stereo.

I tried to use amerge and amix filters they worked great but both had one problem - the volume in the resulting mix was lower than in in the source files. 
The command I used was:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y  -i song.mp3 -i track1.mp3  .... -i track[N].mp3  -filter_complex amerge=inputs=[N]  -c:a libmp3lame  -ar 44100 -q:a 1 mix.mp3
```

I also tried to use the pan filter and it worked great for 2 files with
pan=stereo:c0=c0+c1:c1=c0+c1 - the result was exactly what I need but I could not make it work with more than 2 files (and I need to be able to merge up-to 12).

Comment: I would expect proper downmixing to lower the gain to prevent clipping. Instead of `pan` you can simply try `-ac 2`.

Comment: I used `ffmpeg.exe -i Avicii-WakeMeUp.mp3 -i jk0-0.mp3 -i jk0-3.mp3 -ac 2 mixsingers.mp3`. The output file contains only first track. ffmpeg output was: `Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 -> libmp3lame)`
size=    3919kB time=00:04:10.75 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:3918kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.006355%

Comment: You need `amerge` first.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
As said by llogan you need amerge first:

ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp3

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what each step does

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).